# How can I use flowbite in Ruby on Rails 7?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tailwind-css

I want to use the flowbite  css libary for tailwind in ruby on rails bu twhen i try to add it on the `tailwind.config.js` by

```
  plugins: [
    require('flowbite/plugin'),
    require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
    require('@tailwindcss/aspect-ratio'),
    require('@tailwindcss/typography'),
  ]
```

throws a `cannot find file` error

I have already tried to adding the module by `importmap-rails pin` gem

Note: i'm using the `tailwindcss-rails` gem in the project

Comment: This is more recent and cleaner https://stackoverflow.com/a/74671802/393021

Comment: No, that answer addresses only front-end Flowbite JS, not the Flowbite Tailwind plugin requested here.

Answer (score 0):

Just add the dependency by yarn

```
yarn add flowbye
```

also works for daisyui, tailwind ui and other plugins for tailwind