# Flowbite and Turbo Rails 7 with import map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, turbo, flowbite

Please help me, how to use Flowbite and Turbo Rails 7 with import map?
I use Flowbite v.1.5.3 as here https://flowbite.com/docs/getting-started/rails/
and tailwindcss

I found it https://github.com/themesberg/flowbite/issues/88 and i change "DOMContentLoaded" on "turbo:load" in dist/flowbite.js and in vendor/javascript/flowbite.js, but it's not work for me, my scripts work only if reload page

Answer (score 0):

Good news, version `1.5.5` fixed the problem, just replace the old flowbite line in the `importmap.rb` with.

```js
pin "flowbite", to: "https://unpkg.com/flowbite@1.5.5/dist/flowbite.turbo.js"
```

And remove this line if you added it.

```js
Turbo.session.drive = false
```

Comment: Yes, it's a good news, thank you so much!